# analogread() function in a for loop

Tags: arduino

I have 6 sensors connected to the pin `A0`, `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`, `A5` and I am trying to get readings from each sensor. I have a `analogread()` function inside of a for loop and it does not work.

If I just trigger the sensor at `A0`, all other sensors will have the same reading as that one even if they are not triggered. I used a voltage meter to test the voltage of each pin and only got voltage at `A0` when the `A0` sensor is triggered. So I believe this is a coding problem.

Here is my code:

```
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0~5:
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    int sensorValue0 = analogRead(i);  
    delay(700);

    // Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to voltage range (0 - 5V);
    float voltage0 = sensorValue0 * (5.0 / 1023.0);

    // print out the value you read:
    Serial.print(voltage0);Serial.print("    i = ");
    Serial.print(i);Serial.print("   ; ");
    if (i == 5) Serial.println("     ");
  }  
}
```

Comment: your code looks ok, I think it's a circuit issue

Answer (score 0):

I just set up some voltage dividers, consisting of combination of various R1 and R2=1k and hooked them up to the analog inputs of an Arduino. Using your code, I received the following data (S0 = raw reading, V0 =  calculated voltage)

```
R1    S0    V0
220   841   4.11
470   695   3.40
1k    511   2.50
2k2   318   1.55
4k7   179   0.87
6k8   128   0.63
```

This looks fine. Your code is correct. There's definitely something wrong with your wiring.